# How to hide one CSS element based on another element's toggled state via jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hide

Long time lurker, first time asker. I normally find something in this great community that helps me, but I'm coming up short here.

I have two toggles for elements. These are only visible when the media screen is less than 600px. The first is a menu button that toggles my menu visibility. The second is a search bar button that toggles the search bar visibility.

When the menu is active, it does some unwanted things to an active search bar. Since I don't really care if the search bar is open when the menu is active, I'd like to hide the search button toggle when the menu is active. I figure using jQuery would be the best option. I'm not good at jQuery.

Below are a some selections I've been playing with to no success.

Here's what I have for jQuery:

```
 jQuery(document).each(function($){
    if($('.menu-toggle').css('display') === 'none') {
       $('.search-toggle').hide();
      }
 });
```

And for CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .search-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
        height: 3.75em;
        padding: 0 1em;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 3.75em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        /*button style*/
        background: none;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        text-shadow: none;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        font-size: 12px
    }
    .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
        display: block;
        border-top: 1px solid white;
        background: #1e222b;
    }
    /* Full-Width Menu */
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `jQuery(document).ready` and if you wish you can use `$('.menu-toggle').is(':visible')`

Comment: Can you post your html code please